# Ordered rank in PostgreSQL only for specific rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm on PostgreSQL and I'm trying to find a query that can solve my problem.

This is what I need:

```
|COL1|COL2|COL3|RANK
| A  | G  | V2 | NULL
| A  | B  | V1 | 1
| A  | C  | V1 | 1
| A  | D  | V1 | 1
| A  | D  | V2 | NULL
| A  | E  | V1 | 2
```

In short, for consecutive rows, ordered by COL1-COL2, I need to get an ordered RANK for COL3 = V1.

I was thinking to use the **LAG()** function, for checking the next row, and then compare the value of COL3 between current row and next row, with something like this:

```
SELECT *, lag(COL3) over(partition by COL1 order by COL1, COL2) as COL_CHECK
FROM table
```

I don't really understand how can I manage this, because I need RANK column **NULL** when COL3 = V2, and increase RANK when COL3 = V1.

Thank you.

Comment: You have non-deterministic order here ! Is there any column we can depend on to get the data arranged the way you've showed it?

Comment: Why don't you write one SQL for COL3='V1' that calculates a rank and then UNION it with a query for COL3<>'V1'?

Comment: @SelVazi what about if I create a column using the row_number function? Because this table comes out from aggregations and other steps, so I don't have a primary key for them.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer this can also be an idea. I'm trying both solutions and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Yes `row_number()` can do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists a unique column ensuring deterministic ordering (such as a primary key), here's a solution employing the difference between two row numbers:

```
select *, case when col3 = 'V1'
               then row_number() over (partition by COL1 order by id) -
                    row_number() over (partition by COL1, COL3 order by id)
               else null 
          end as rnk
from mytable
order by id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q5RioE4r)